# Forwarding data from a pipe

Tags: linux, cat, netcat

I want to do a pipe line in the order below. Data is returned from the nc request.

```
cat myfile | nc 127.0.0.1 1542 | other_app
```

Problem is cat finishes quickly, pipe is stopped and other_app is forwarded nothing.

How to pass other_app the data that is returned from nc?

Comment: `netcat` uses two parameters, destination and port, not three. You are trying to do something like `nc 127.0.0.1 1542 $(cat myfile)`, what's inside your file and can you show what you want to do with a piece of content of your file?

Answer (score 0):

For sending/receiving basic example:

In the receiver:

```
nc -l 8080 > tmp.out
```

In the sender:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8080 < file
```

If in the receiver besides writing to a file you would like to pipe the input to another "app" you could use something like:

```
nc -l 8080 | tee -a tmp.out | cat
```